# Why isn't an article used in which/what sentences such as "what flavor would you like"?

Tags: articles, zero-article, wh-questions

Why **aren't** articles used in which or what questions? (**For example**: "What flavor would you like?") Can I say "what **a** flavor would you like?"?

Comment: Why do you think articles aren't used in questions that start with which or what? *What the hell are you doing?* / *Which is the one you prefer?*

Answer (score 1):

Articles are not needed when there is some other determiner:

> A dog  / my dog / that dog

The words my and that are determiners and you don't say "my a dog" or "the my dog"

Articles ('a' and 'the') are also determiners.

The question word "what" can also function as a determiner, although it asks for the responder to determine.  So again we don't say "what a dog is it?" or "The what dog is it?"